# CSS : Removings dots in a list removes all the effects

Tags: css, html-lists

I want to remove the dots in a **ul**  but when I do, the height of the **ul** is reduced to 0px, so the contained **li** s have a transparent background. Can you give me an alternative ? This is the code :

```
<ul class="class_1" style="z-index: 1; top: -557.15px; left: 801px; display: block; position: relative; width: 200px;">
    <li class="class_2">
        <a>Ba</a>
    </li>
    <li class="class_2">
        <a>Baa</a>
    </li>
    <li class="class_2">
        <a>Baar</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<style>
li {
    list-style-type: none;
}
.class1
{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border: 1px solid;
}
</style>
```

Thanks.

Comment: anychance of a http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: how do you remove those dots?  show it on jsfiddle

Comment: In any case you should set list-style: none on the UL, not on the LI

Comment: And: your problem must be in a part of the code you are not displaying in your question. When i copy paste your content to a standalone html file, there are no problems (aside from the top/left moving the content off the screen, but when those are removed everything is fine)

Answer (score 1):

add css style for `<li>` elements - add `display:block` for them as well. that should do the trick, assuming there's no other style that is messing with this `<ul>`